# React Native: StyleError = StyleSheetValidation

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I'm stuck at the moment with this error when running my RN build on AVD.

It was working last night, but for some reason it stopped working now.

I've not done any change but simply move my android SDK folder to another drive and I have updated all my environment variables accordingly.

When i load my build to the AVD, i get this error:
[image]

It doesn't seem to be a script error on my side because even if I copy the exact codes from the RN tutorial, it still gives this error.

I googled and it seems I am alone with this error, so I'm a bit stuck.

How do I troubleshoot/fix this? (im just starting out w/ Android stuffs)

Comment: Can you add your index.android.js code. Trace shows error coming from line 65 of index.android.js

Comment: it started working again for some reason.. strange. perhaps a packager error ?